# How do you remove a parent element's rotate from a child element?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have a parent element that rotates a child element. When I click a button I want the child element to animate to the position it would be in if there were no rotate applied to the parent but the parent should remain rotated.

If you just subtract the rotate of the parent on the child it only works with rotateZ

```
.parent { -webkit-transform:rotateX(45deg); }
.child { -webkit-transform:rotateX(-45deg); }
```

[image]

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yzw68/)

Answer (score 2):

Rotating the child by 180deg minus rotation of parent worked for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/e9raN/

```
#parent {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(30deg) rotateY(30deg);
}

#child {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(150deg) rotateY(150deg);
}
```

I don't know why negative is not working, but this seems to be the only solution.